# How do I write a Jmeter script without using the GUI?

Tags: jmeter

Is there a way to create a JMeter test plan without going through the GUI?

I.E. can you create a script with pure code?

Comment: Are you referring to JMX (as in the title) or JMS as in the question text ?

Comment: Are you trying to write a jmeter script without using the GUI?

Comment: You can run jmetere from non-GUI command line but I doubt if you can create jmeter script without GUI. If you already have a Jmeter script then ofcourse you can edit it in some XML editor or plain vanilla editor.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but here is one alternative. https://github.com/flood-io/ruby-jmeter Please note that its not complete/comprehensive, so better read the docs to see if it satisfies your need.

Answer (score 1):

In a way - yes.  You can create the JMX file in a text editor, but it would require knowing what every component needs.

You're better off creating in GUI mode and modifying the JMX file manually as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to write a test plan just by writing JAVA code.
The key classes to look into are:
StandardJMeterEngine - the main class which configures the Test Plan and executes it
HashTree - a special collection which holds Test Plan elements
A minimum of JMeter Controllers necessary to run the test.

Reference: http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui

Answer (score 0):

I can write and run JMeter without GUI. JMeter use [JMX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Management_Extensions) file, as you can [here](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/jakarta-jmeter-2.4/bin/testfiles/GuiTest.jmx.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure why you would want to write a JMX in this way? ... But yes, entirely possible if you understand the structure of the document.

You could use any basic text editor to achieve this (notepad / notepad++ for example).

> A JMX file is a saved JMeter project in XML format. [~ Ref](https://doc.octoperf.com/design/create-virtual-user/import-jmeter-jmx/)

Depending on your needs you could the browser editor from the JMeter Plugins website.

[jmeter-plugins.org/editor/](https://jmeter-plugins.org/editor/)

Or simply save a basic JMX as a template and spend loads of time learning the structure, syntax and namings etc.